# Updating Records while leaving part of the record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to update two tables containing account names /building names after Winn-Dixie's purchase of Sweetbay. The account table has two columns I'd like to update: name and internalname. The name column should be straight forward as I'd update the records where anything is like 'Sweetbay%' but the internalname is trickier it contains names like "Sweetbay Supermarket - New Tampa' or 'Sweetbay Supermarket - Palmetto'.  In these cases, I'd like to keep the text after the "-" so it becomes "Winn-Dixie - New Tampa" or "Winn-Dixie - Palmetto".

What would be the best way to handle this? Any suggestions?

Also, I'd like to began clean up on the naming convention of "Winn-Dixie" as well because there are instances of the account "Winn Dixie" that should include the "-" to standardize the convention.  I believe this would be done the same way as above.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cases you mention are all there is, then try some string manipulation (see `REPLACE` and other string functions [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx))

E.g.

```
UPDATE #Table 
SET name = 'Winn-Dixie -' + RIGHT(Name, LEN(NAME) - CHARINDEX('-',Name))
WHERE name LIKE 'Sweetbay%'
```

But in real life scenarios you cannot go through all the records, identify each change necessary and code around it. There are tools specifically targeted to that. Try looking up `data cleansing`.

I remember a presentation of [MS's Data Quality Projects (DQS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213052.aspx). It seemed quite promising, but I'm sure there are other tools out there too.

In the end human interaction is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks adaskos, I looked up REPLACE and it looks like it might do the trick but data cleansing is a reason we recently built a SQL 2012 server so I'll also see what it can do.